# Having issues interfacing SPS30 with Pico

Tags: sensor, uart, pi-pico

I am trying to interface SPS30 via UART, but I am not able to start the fan. I am getting some response but it won't match any possible response from the datasheet. Using Micropython.
Below is the code snippet -

```
import machine
import time
from micropython import const
if __name__ == "__main__":
   uart=machine.UART(1,115200,tx=machine.Pin(4),rx=machine.Pin(5)
   uart.write(bytes(0xff))
   buffer=[0x7e,0x00,0x11,0x00,0xee,0x7e]
   uart.write(bytes(buffer))
   uart.write(bytes(buffer))
   response=uart.read()
   print(response)
   time.sleep(1)
   buffer=[0x7e,0x00,0x03,0x00,0xfc,0x7e]
   uart.write(bytes(buffer))
   response=uart.read()
   print (response)
```

And response that I am getting -

```
b'\xfe~\x00}1C\x00\xab~'
b'~\x00}1C\x00\xab~'
```

Comment: Are you using the particular model: Datasheet SPS30 Particulate Matter Sensor for Air Quality Monitoring and Control
https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/2/d/2/a/6/Sensirion_SPS30_Particulate_Matter_Sensor_v0.9_D1__1_.pdf

Comment: I would suggest to first make sure Pico UART/serial loopback test is OK.

Comment: @tlfong01 yes I am using this model only. I have tested UART works with another sensor that I have used over UART. To be clear, not using both sensors on uart at once. The previous sensor is from different project.

Comment: What does this command do: [0x7e,0x00,0x11,0x00,0xee,0x7e]? Pls let me know which section of the datasheet you are reading.

Comment: This is wake up command. Cmd:0x11. Pg 12 of datasheet.

Comment: It appears that we are not reading the same datasheet.  Can you give me the link to your datasheet?

Comment: https://sensirion.com/media/documents/8600FF88/616542B5/Sensirion_PM_Sensors_Datasheet_SPS30.pdf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136626/discussion-between-tlfong01-and-robot).

Comment: The question in this thread is resolved. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome.  Have a nice weekend. Cheers.